# Postgres docker-image won't run and won't start

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I run

```
docker-compose up
```

I get:

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting asynchttpproxy_db_1
Starting asynchttpproxy_web_1
Attaching to asynchttpproxy_db_1, asynchttpproxy_web_1
db_1   | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-05-01 05:11:54 UTC
db_1   | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1   | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  |
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.
<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fae3f078e18>
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
web_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 176, in 
get_new_connection
web_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
web_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, 
async=async)
web_1  | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection 
refused
web_1  |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and 
accepting
web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1  | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web_1  |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and 
accepting
web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1  |
web_1  |
web_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following 
exception:
web_1  |
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
web_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in 
inner_run
web_1  |     self.check_migrations()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 168, in 
check_migrations
web_1  |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
web_1  |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
web_1  |     self.build_graph()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 182, in build_graph
web_1  |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
web_1  |     self.ensure_schema()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
web_1  |     if self.Migration._meta.db_table in 
self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 162, in cursor
web_1  |     cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
web_1  |     self.ensure_connection()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", 
line 97, in __exit__
web_1  |     six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/utils/six.py", line 658, in reraise
web_1  |     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
web_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-pac 
kages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 176, in 
get_new_connection
web_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
```

I go to /c/program files/postgresql/9.3/

I do

```
postgres -D data
```

I get

```
$ postgres -D data
2017-05-01 00:18:14 CDT LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: No error
2017-05-01 00:18:14 CDT HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 
5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2017-05-01 00:18:14 CDT LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: No error
2017-05-01 00:18:14 CDT HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 
5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2017-05-01 00:18:14 CDT WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "*"
2017-05-01 00:18:14 CDT FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
```

My DATABASES in my settings.py is:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'async_http_proxy2',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I don't know what to do at this point. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your **docker-compose.yml** create a link between the postgres container and your django container and expose their ports

```
postgres:
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - ./postgres/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  env_file:
    - .env
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app/static
  expose:
    - '5432'
web:
  build: .
  env_file:
    - .env
  volumes: 
    - .:/code
  links:
    - postgres
  expose:
    - '8000'
```

Create an .env file like:

```
DB_NAME=async_http_proxy2
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS=your_password
DB_SERVICE=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
```

then create an **docker-entrypoint-initdb.d** file to create the database

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE USER $DB_USER WITH PASSWORD '$DB_PASS';
    CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $DB_NAME TO $DB_USER;
EOSQL
```

then in **settings.py** change the database settings to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
    'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
    'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS'),
    'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_SERVICE'),
    'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT'), 
    }
}
```

**TAKE NOTE**

It's good to take advantage of the env file to hide important keys and credentials

After making changes on the files try doing the build again `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: Hey Dean, how might I ensure that the Django webserver is automatically started when I run "docker compose up"? Also, must I modify postgres.volumes after the build? Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, when running "docker-compose up --build" when django is trying to start the web server I get "psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "async_http_proxy3" does not exist'

Comment: @MikeJohnsonJr, you need to set that up on the `DB_NAME` in the .env file and django webserver must automatically be started after running `docker-compose up`.. You can check by running `docker-compose ps`

Answer (score 2):

your django configuration is set to be looking for the DB in localhost, however since django runs in a container the localhost it refers to is the container itself, in the compose file case it should be

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'async_http_proxy2',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

becouse docker-compose creates a network for you with a simple name resolution.
so in your case when your compose is using 'db' as the service name that is the name your django('web') container will be able to get to the DB